# Check PDF for Viruses

Tags: pdf, virus, anti-virus

I found this on Github.

https://github.com/alitekdemir/Python-Books/blob/master/Jon%20Erickson%20-%20Hacking%20Art%20of%20Exploitation.pdf

I wan't to support the real author with buying it, but before I want to test the book and do you think the PDF is safe?

And how can I test an PDF?

Comment: See [How to scan a PDF for malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2896)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender can scan it or any antivirus on your PC. Otherwise there are a lot of virus scanning websites: Virustotal.com, other vendors (Norton, trend micro, etc.)

Comment: Is Virustotal detecting PDF Files?